# Security role for activity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I would like to find out if we can restrict users to only response or close activities that only assign to them in MS Dynamics CRM 2016. Please advise which permission that I should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the security role privilege for Activity like below:

This is basically allowing current owner (user level or basic privilege) can only read/edit any activity record.

[image]

But the catch is this will apply to all activity types like email, fax, task, appointment, etc.